# Android - Auto wraped according to screen resolution

Tags: android

I have button series.ex.10 buttons.According to screen size it should be wrapped to 2 or 3 rows when rotating screen.How can i do that in Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is always this http://nishantvnair.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/flowlayout-in-android/

Else, a GridView can do if your buttons are all the same size.